# Using Python to Loop Through Variables in an API Request

Tags: python, api, loops, python-requests, screen-scraping

I want to use one script to make a series of API calls for a list of addresses/ids. The issue is that when I run the script, I eventually get a timeout. Othertimes the address variable embeddded into data_request isn't recognized.
Below is my current code.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
import time

    with open('TransactionHistory.csv','a') as f: 
        while True:
            addresses=["0xe3457148b4f535b7a42bf6aaa06c6c92a0b9f9cb", "0xad8f33994ec88ab208ada1d286b41c4a39515aed"]
                for address in addresses:

                data_request=requests.get("http://api.etherscan.io/api? module=account&action=txlist&address="+address+"=5585000&endblock=5590000&sort=asc&apikey=SZAEWWTN9YXQNR4X593AUDB7Y5323D6CAE") 
                json=data_request.json()
                df = pd.DataFrame(json,dtype=object,index=[0])
                [df.to_csv(f, header=False) for i in range (1)] 
                time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: The issue is that when I run the script, I eventually get a timeout. Othertimes the address variable embeddded into data_request isn't recognized.

Comment: Please lay out your code correctly, and also describe exactly what the error is by cutting and pasting the error message.

Comment: Just finished laying it out.

Comment: There is a full stack trace, but here is the beginning of the error: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-71f6c878576e> in <module>()
     13                 data_request=requests.get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address="+address+"=5585000&endblock=5590000&sort=asc&apikey=SZAEWWTN9YXQNR4X593AUDB7Y5323D6CAE")
     14                 json=data_request.json()
---> 15                 df = pd.DataFrame(json,dtype=object,index=[0])

Answer (score 0):

You have a "while True:" in your code, so it looks like it will loop forever. Most public API's have a rate/call limit, and will timeout after you hit it. My guess is that you're hitting the API until it just stops answering you.

Try removing the "while True" loop, and stepping through your code to see if it logically makes sense.

Comment: Awesome. I am going to think this through and see if it works. I'll report back. Appreciate the patience as I work through teaching myself how to code.

Comment: No problem - we all started somewhere :)

Comment: It usually helps me to run python with the debugger. There's a good tutorial here:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-python-debugger

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured it out. I just needed to slow down and de-bug my code line-by-line. A little patience goes a long way!

Comment: If the author isn't going to post/vote for a solution, this question should be deleted.